# DataContract classes uninitialized at client side

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have the following class I'd like to send from my `WCF` (`C#`) service to my client (`WPF`):

```
[DataContract]
    public class OutputAvailableEventArgs
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsError { get; private set; }

        public OutputAvailableEventArgs(int id) : this(id, false, "") { }

        public OutputAvailableEventArgs(int id, string output) : this(id, false, output) { }

        public OutputAvailableEventArgs(int id, bool isError, string output)
        {
            ID = id;
            IsError = isError;
            Message = output;
        }
    }
```

It's used by the service as follows:

```
var channel = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();

channel.OutputAvailable(new OutputAvailableEventArgs(1, false, "some message"));
```

At the client side, the members get their default values.
I tried marking them with `IsRequired` attribute but now the `OutputAvailable` at the client is not called. The code at the service side seems to run smoothly (I didn't notice anything with the debugger).

How can I transfer a `DataContract` class with `WCF` while maintaining the members' values?
(I saw solutions that suggested to use `OnSerialized` and `OnDeserialized` but I don't need just a default constructor.)

Comment: If possible, use fiddler to see what is being returned by Service and what is being received by Client in message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw many different solutions for this problem. For other people's sake I'll write some of them down + what worked for me:

1. It seems that in some cases specifying the items' order solves the problem. Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474838/not-all-parameters-in-wcf-data-contract-make-it-through-the-web-service-call) for full details.
2. If it's some default initialization you're after, you can use `OnSerialized` and `OnDeserialized` methods to call your initialization methods.
3. I also tried using the `IsRequired` attribute on my `DataMember`s but still didn't get my objects.

What worked for me was [adding `NameSpace` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525669/427653) in the `DataContract` attribute. Apparently, In order to have the contracts be considered equal, you must set the Namespace property on the DataContract to the same value on both sides.